# Why was the C++ string converted to int?

Tags: c++, string, int

In the following code, I can not understand why the `string` is converted to `int` in this way.

Why is it using a sum with `0` ?

```
string mystring; 
vector<int> myint; 
mystring[i+1]=myint[i]+'0';
```

Comment: You won't understand it since this code won't convert string to int.

Comment: Or it may do so? I want [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Isn't there some sort of a loop missing here. The `i+1` sure does indicate that. Providing the context of this code snippet might give us some extra information and enable us to maybe also explain why this whole things is done to begin with.

Comment: I think this is not string -> int conversion, but int -> string conversion.

Comment: Looks like you need some help on ASCII tables char and integer variables, casting etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code converts an int (presumably a digit) to the character that represents it.

Since characters are sequential, and `char`s can be treated as integers, the character representing a certain digit can, in fact, be described by its distance from `'0'`. This way, `0` turns turn to the character `'0'`, `'5'` is the character that is greater than `'0'` by five, and so on.

Comment: Since characters are sequential... _in ASCII_

Answer (score 2):

This is an efficient, old school and dangerous method to get a char representation of a single digit. `'0'` will be converted to an `int` containing its ASCII code (0x30 for '0') and then that is added to `myint[i]`. If `myint[i]` is `9` or lower, you can cast `myint[i]` to a char you will get the resulting digit as text.

Things will not go as expected if you add more than `9` to `'0'`

You can also get a number from its char representation :

```
char text = '5';
int digit = text - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `'0'` expression isn't string type, it's char type that stores characters of ASCII and also can represent numbers from 0 to 255. So, in arithmetic operations char behaves like integer type.

In C strings a represent as arrays of char: static (`char str[N]`) or dynamic (`char *str = new char[n]`). String literals puts into double quotes (`"string"`).
So, `'0'` is char and `"0"` is char[1]